# Problems when installing 2amigos datepicker via Composer

Tags: php, composer-php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to install [2amigos date picker](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-date-picker-widget) in Yii2, but I'm getting the following error:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced>php composer.phar require "2amigos/yii2-date-picker-widget" "*"
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.2 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.2 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for yiisoft/yii2 == 2.0.2.0 -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2[2.0.2].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I have tried editing the `composer.json` file, changing `minimum-stability` to `dev`, but this still don't work.

Comment: Did you install composer asset plugin? `composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.0"` http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html#installing-via-composer

Comment: just did this and i got the follow..

'Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing fxp/composer-asset-plugin (v1.0.0)
    Downloading: 100%


Fatal error: Class 'Composer\Installer\InstallerEvents' not found in C:\Users\Nerison\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\fxp\composer-asset-plugin\FxpAssetPlugin.php on line 75
'

Comment: Installed it right now without any problems. Try to update `composer` to the latest version with `self-update` command.

Comment: Glad to help, issued that as an answer.

Comment: Same goes for me. Thanks again @arogachev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to install composer asset plugin with the following command:

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.0"
```

It should be only executed once.

Read more in [official guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html#installing-via-composer) and [plugin official documentation](https://github.com/francoispluchino/composer-asset-plugin).

In case of other problems during installation update `composer` to the latest version with `self-update` command.